# Disabling a certain item in a QCombobox - PyQt6

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt6

I have 4 comboboxes. Every one has a placeholder, and they initially all hold the same list of items. When the user selects an item from one of them, I want it removed from the other 3, but without affecting them. If I use clear() then add a new list, the current choice of other lists will be reset. Completely removing the item doesn't work too -- What if the user decides to choose a different item after that? The removed item doesn't come back to the other boxes, and a different item will be deleted. I'm not sure if creating variables to hold removed data and insert it later on is a valid idea, and I can't exactly imagine how to implement it anyway.
Thanks!

Edit:
An alternative way to go about this is to basically "disable" the item in question in other comboboxes, rather than completely remove it or such, but I can't seem to find a way to do that. Other answers to this question on here are very old, and pretty much all of them are in C++ rather than Python.

Comment: The approach doesn't seem very solid. Consider an opposite case: what if the user wants to select an item in a combo that has been already selected in another? And what if there aren't as many items to "swap" that situation (a simple case, each combo only has 4 items). The result would be that as soon as you select an item from tree combos, you'll be completely blocked out (consider the "Hanoi tower problem"). A more appropriate behavior would be to add some sanity check that would be activated by item changes and eventually proceed as long as *all* boxes have different items.

Comment: @musicamante That's the thing -- I do NOT want to allow the user to select an item that has already been selected in another, AT ALL. That's the whole reason of why I want to remove it from other boxes. My program has things and values that change dynamically based on some of this stuff -- I imagine a "sanity check" would only be really practical when the final step is a "button" thing, which it's not and is not practical for me to make it like that, which is why I posted here.

Comment: And, again, that's exactly the issue of your approach: such circular system that disables or removes options does *not* work well, especially if there are not enough options. Please read the first part of my comment, because that is valid in both cases, whether you remove items or disable them.

Comment: @Yuuna I don't see why removing the items would cause any problems. The user can only select one item at a time, so it's not possible for there to ever be any conflicts, since the choices are guaranteed to be mutually exclusive. If the user changes their mind about one choice, they can simply unselect their previous choices as necessary.

Comment: @ekhumoro The problem is that the removed items won't come back if the user changes their mind and unselect their previous choices.

Comment: @Yuuna I don't see any problems. The "removal" can be done by hiding/disabling the relevant items via [the model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#model). Or the items can be refreshed from a separate master-list.

Comment: @ekhumoro I've pursued that route and came up empty. All solutions I found in that regard were in C++, also I'm not advanced in qt yet, but most were assuming what's called a QStandardItemModel, but qcombobox uses a QAbstractItemModel, so even if I somehow understood the C++ code, I wouldn't be able to transfer it into python, which is why I reposted the question here. Also, as I mentioned in my post, if "refreshing" is what I think it is of clearing and repopulating, then that process removes the currently selected item in other boxes, which I don't want.

Comment: @Yuuna The default model of QComboBox is a QStandardItemModel (which you could have easily confirmed for yourself by checking the return value).

Comment: @ekhumoro Well when I call model() on any combobox in my program, it certainly says that it returns a QAbstractItemModel. I'm not sure if this is intended, and if it is not, I have no idea what the issue is. At least in my program, combobox.model().item() does not do anything at all, and I'm assuming because item() is a method for a QStandardItemModel while I'm trying to call it on a QAbstractItemModel. Again, not saying you're wrong but that's just what's happening right now for me.

Comment: @Yuuna What certainly says? Your IDE? Here is what I see in a python interactive session: `from PyQt6 import QtWidgets; app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['']); c = QtWidgets.QComboBox(); c.model()` => `<PyQt6.QtGui.QStandardItemModel object at 0x7f00216b3370>`. And also: `c.model().addItems('One Two Three'.split()); c.model().item(0)` => `<PyQt6.QtGui.QStandardItem object at 0x7f00216b3400>`. Please do some basic testing rather than making assumptions.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for the persuasion, I needed it. Yes my IDE was saying so; VS Code tells you the return type when you hover over a method, and it said QAbstractItemModel so I didn't bother trying to print it. It was even more confusing since I couldn't auto-complete any methods that come with the QStandardItemModel, so I thought for sure it's a QAbstractItemModel as the IDE says. I made a temporary workaround by changing the currentIndex to -1 whenever the user selects a choice that == currentText of another combobox. I will be shifting from this soon though now that I figured this out!